# Copy Value of Local into Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Trying to find the correct way to do this, but can't seem to find the correct syntax anywhere..

all I want to do is copy the the value of a local variable into a pointer, so I may use that pointer anywhere. Otherwise when the method returns the value of the that pointer will be unpredictable.. Heres what I have but it seems to still just reference the address of the local variable

```
void method(){

 unsigned int localValue = 0x00FF00AA;
 unsigned int *point = (unsigned int *) 0x00000000;
 *point = localValue;
}
```

but this code just seg faults. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have a serious misunderstanding of pointers, but the exact nature of that misunderstanding is unclear to me.  Part of the problem may be that you are not distinguishing between a pointer value and the object, if any, to which that value *points*.  These are completely separate things.

Answer (score 1):

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

> In C code, segmentation faults most often occur because of errors in
>   pointer use. Dereferencing a null pointer will always result in a segmentation fault, but wild pointers and dangling pointers point to memory that may or may not exist, and may or may not be readable or writable, and thus can result in transient bugs.

```
line 8        *point = localValue;
```

Here your assigning local value to the pointer that causing the SIGSEGV.

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void method(){
    unsigned int localValue = 0x00FF00AA;
    unsigned int *point = &localValue;
    printf("%p\n", *point); //this just debug code
}

int main(void) {
    method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: completely true. I failed to remove that, Its redundant.

Comment: Please do not edit the question so that the answers do not make sense. Just append to it.

Comment: Yes, that I did yesterday itself. I thought the comment is about the latest edit. It was redundant statement, which I failed to remove it. Hereafter I will append it as comment to the answer

Answer (score 0):

It seg faults, beacause you are trying to write via a NULL pointer.

You can directly give to your pointer the address of the integer you want to use, by using the &-operator.

```
unsigned int localValue = 0x00FF00AA;
unsigned int *point = &localValue;
```

**EDIT**: After the really helpful comments below, I noticed that my first sentence might be wrong, even if it is only a little detail, that makes it sound so. What you are trying to do is *not* write to a NULL pointer, but dereference it, in order to write to the (non-existent) object it points to.

Comment: At the risk of sounding pedantic, he is not trying to write to a null pointer.  He is *dereferencing* a null pointer so as to attempt to write to the (non-existent) object to which it points.  I emphasize this because I suspect the OP's confusion arises at least in part from just this kind of distinction.

Comment: I agree with @John Bollinger and propose an efficient way for phrasing: "OP is writing **via** a NULL pointer."

Answer (score 0):

```
point = (unsigned int*) localValue;
```

The variable "point" (being a pointer) is set to the value of the variable "localValue".
To do that, a type cast is recommended, to tell the compiler that this unsigned integer value is now the address to an unsigned integer. Accepting input from a comment: the cast is required.

If you use the pointer later be careful.
Make sure that the integer value is an address of a part of memory which you really want to use; especially when writing.
It is probably OK if it happens for example to be a writeable memory-mapped peripheral register on a microcontroller.

Comment: Technically, a cast is *required* for that assignment, not merely recommended.  Some compilers will accept it without, but that's an extension.  I'm inclined to doubt that that's what the OP actually wants to achieve, however, because I don't see how it serves the purpose of "so I may use that pointer anywhere".  I think his misunderstanding is deeper.

Comment: @John Bollinger thanks for the input on "cast required", I have to be careful with too strict phrasings in my job. Otherwise, OP states he wants to "copy the the value of a local variable into a pointer". That sounds pretty precise. "use that pointer anywhere", I assume, implies that he is going to make the pointer visible everywhere and hopefully global. That I considered out of scope.